Why does clearly defined land ownership push land price higher?
I have no economics background. I read about Enclosure Movement in British history. I was told that enclosure was a process of confirmation of land ownership. I was also told that clearly defined ownership pushed land price higher, so that as long as a farmer was able to buy the land on which he was working from his lord, his land would have a higher value.
I want to ask about the reason behind this.
I searched for some relavant knowledge, and I found Demsetz Conjecture. But it seems to me that it only explains that clearly defined property rights would emerge if potential gains are greater than the cost of establishing such rights. It does not seem to explain why clearly defined property rights bring potential gains greater than the cost.
